# CloudKit automatic background backup

Tags: swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I'm currently working on a project that uses `CoreData` for data saving in swift, and for the purpose of synchronization I wanted to use iCloud, and the first thing I thought was on the `CoreData iCloud` implementation, but since it's now marked as deprecated I started using `CloudKit`, and everything works fine until I try to make a backup of the information after an internet connection is stablished (in case of failure when the information should be updated), the app does not store files, just data, all `CKRecords` are working fine.

**My questions are:**

1. Can you synchronize the information after the application is terminated?
2. Does `CloudKit` connect to the automatic iCloud synchronization, the one that happens when the device is plugged and has an internet connection.

**The current structure is:**
`CoreData` for local saving and withdrawal of data, and `CloudKit` for Cloud synchronization.

**So far I understand that:** `CloudKit` does not interact directly with `CoreData` and all actions involving data synchronization must be done with the Api calls.

Thank you for your help and if I forgot something please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When your app is terminated it isn't running so you can't sync anything. You would need to re-launch your app (possibly into the background?), but there are some serious limits to what you can do to have that happen without user intervention. Here's a couple threads that might shed more light: [Launch app in background automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867117/launch-app-in-background-automatically) and [Will iOS launch my app into the background if it was force-quit by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-force-quit-by-the-user)

2) Out of the box CloudKit doesn't do anything 'automatically', it does what you tell it to do. You will need to set it up to fire at appropriate times in your code (when something changes), and in response to push notification for changes from other devices.